# Question on polynomial approximation of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am solving this past year qualifying exam question.

Consider the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ on the annulus $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \frac{1}{2}<|z|<2\}$. I have to show that there is a sequence $\{r_n(z)\}$ of rational functions whose poles are contained in $\mathbb{C} - A$ and which approximates $f(z)$ uniformly on compact subsets of $A$.

I am not sure how to proceed to solve this problem. Also, I am not sure what topics should I cover to solve problems like these.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: What is $A$? And should $\mathbb C - \{A \}$ perhaps be $\mathbb C - A$?

Comment: $f(z)$ is already a rational function! You can take $r_n(z)=1/z$ for all $n$, it should be trivially correct.

Comment: @crostul Thank you for the reply. Then what about the condition that poles of $r_n(z)$ is contained in $\mathbb{C}-A$? Since pole of $r_n$ will be $0$ which lies inside A. Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Actually $0 \notin A$, because $|0|=0 < 1/2$.

Comment: @Crostul Oh right I asked a very silly question. :) Thank you very much.